# how to parse html files in pyspark and use Beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, apache-spark, beautifulsoup, pyspark, hdfs

I have a very difficult situation:
I need to parse a bunch of html files in **pyspark**, but I still want to use **BeautifulSoup** to parse html files. The dilemma is:

1. If I saved these html files in **HDFS**, and use pyspark to read html files in, I can only read them as **RDD**, but I cannot pass RDD as the input parameter in BeautifulSoup;
2. If I saved these html files in local, and use BeautifulSoup to parse html files, the power of pyspark is not been used.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a UDF function in PySpark that would take this HTML column and return extracted fields from HTML, and then call it against DataFrame or RDD, whatever fits best your problem.